# How to ensure a field is populated before use in a trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

When I assign a new bed number in a hospital, the number must be prefixed by the ward number the bed is in. How do I know my user is going to populate Ward_Id before Bed_Id? What does one do in a case like this?

There is only one table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bed](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Bed_Id] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WardId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Private] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SpecialInfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AdministratorId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bed] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

When a bed gets added, `Bed_Id` must be prefixed by `WardId`.

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

You could use a computed column for `BedId`. No need to be actually stored.

Would something like `Bedid AS CONCAT(WardId, '-', Id)` work for you?